# PowerPivot Window won't show: - Index out of range

Tags: powerpivot

PowerPivot for Excel workbook with 14 tables. The powerpivot window opens but does not display any data. The error received is

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I found one possible solution. In this case the diagram view was still available, and I had one calculated column which was in error. I deleted this column from the diagram view and the table view was visible once more.

Interestingly, the same table had measures which were in error, but these did not cause issues.